# bilateral symmetry: word for clockwise rotation on right and counterclockwise on left

Tags: morphology

It seems like there should be some terminology for bilaterally symmetric organisms that could be used in descriptions, where a clockwise rotation on the right is equivalent to counterclockwise rotation on the left. Is there a name for this type of rotation?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your description - do you mean mirrored motions - like if you swim the breast-stroke or butterfly (or bird's wings flapping etc?). If so there are so many motions possible, there isn't a single term.

Comment: radial symmetry?